# Gaps in plots of equation solution from parameter

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm trying to plot solution of system of equations as a function of parameter

```
Manipulate[{
  Quiet[sol = Solve[{Ka*P*L*L == PLL, P0 == P + PLL, r*P0 == L + 2*PLL}, {P, L, PLL}]][[3]];
  complex[x_] := PLL /. sol[[3]] /. r -> x;
  Plot[{
     Hold[Evaluate@D[complex[r], r]],
     Hold[Evaluate@D[-complex[r], {r, 2}]]
     } // Release,
   {r, 0.1, 4},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}
   ]},
 {Ka, 10000, 10000},
 {P0, 0.5, 1}
 ]
```

My plot has gaps! Why and how I can eliminate them?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thre is a small imaginary part due to numerical errors. Just add `Re` inside `Evaluate`:

```
... Evaluate@Re@D[...] ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One way, which I would favor, is to use `Chop` to remove small imaginary parts.  (I would favor this in the case that large imaginary parts should not be ignored, but indicate that the actual solution is not real.)

```
Manipulate[
 With[{sol = 
    Quiet[Solve[{Ka*P*L*L == PLL, P0 == P + PLL, r*P0 == L + 2*PLL}, {P, L, PLL}]][[3]]},
  With[{df = D[PLL /. sol, r], d2f = D[PLL /. sol, {r, 2}]},
   Plot[{Chop[df], Chop[-d2f]}, {r, 0.1, 4}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
   ]],
 {Ka, 10000, 10000}, {P0, 0.5, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]