# Problems with the plot of a function.

Tags: plotting

For some reason the result of Plot of the following function:

```
Clear[x]; Clear[a]; Clear[b];

m={{(1+1/k)/x^2,1/k},{-1/k,x^2(1-1/k)}};
{{l1,l2},{v1,v2}}=Eigensystem[m];
g = Solve[{0,1}==a v1 + b v2,{a,b}];
alpha = First[a /. g];
beta = First[b /. g];
d[x_, h_, n_]:= alpha l1^n v1 + beta l2^n v2 /. k-> (2 Log[x])/h
Plot[Last[d[x,4,8]], {x,6.78,8}, PlotStyle->Orange]
```

is this

[image]

How can I remove those blank spaces to see the plot of a continuous function?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: The plot displays a nice continuous curve in my machine. Try starting a fresh Mathematica session. ¡Suerte!

Comment: I started a new session and the problem remains the same, but now I know it is a particular problem of mine. ¡Gracias!

Comment: The problem are imaginary residuals. You need to `Chop` your function, then everything is fine.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it is a simple mistake, but one that might occur frequently (and I was stumped belisarius did not catch it immediately). Not sure about closure, but perhaps there is a suitable duplicate around somewhere?

Comment: @Yves Sorry, you're right.  (I did vote for your answer, by the way.)  There are many questions on the site that relate to attempting to `Plot` complex values; would you help me find a good one to mark as the original in this case?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard super - will take a look asap.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard what about this one: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34365/131

Comment: @Yves Thanks.  Please cast your vote. :-)

Comment: @Yves Here is an older one that you answered: [(17202)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17202/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard incredible, no recollection whatsoever  :D

Comment: @YvesKlett Can you appear for a short chat? Your link at top (1: ) did not work.

Answer (score 4):

Your function seems to produce values with small imaginary components, which `Plot` deliberately ignores. If you `Chop` your results, the function seems to plot just fine:

```
m = {{(1 + 1/k)/x^2, 1/k}, {-1/k, x^2 (1 - 1/k)}};
{{l1, l2}, {v1, v2}} = Eigensystem[m];
g = Solve[{0, 1} == a v1 + b v2, {a, b}];
alpha = First[a /. g];
beta = First[b /. g];
d[x_, h_, n_] := alpha l1^n v1 + beta l2^n v2 /. k -> (2 Log[x])/h
Plot[Last[d[x, 4, 8]] // Chop, {x, 6.78, 8}, PlotStyle -> Orange]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much. That's it!