# Surviving numerical cusp catastrophe

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

```
EQ = 
  {R''[l] == 0.9897  R[l],  R'[0] == 0, R[0] == 1, 
   Z'[l] == Sqrt[1 - R'[l]^2], Z[0] == 0}; 

NDSolve[EQ, {R, Z}, {l, 0, 2}];

{z[u_], r[u_]} = {Z[u], R[u]} /. First[%];

ParametricPlot[{z[l], r[l]}, {l, 0, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick},  
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  GridLines -> Automatic] 

Table[{l, z[l], r[l], r'[l]}, {l, 0, 2, .2}] // TableForm
```

The output above first plot seems to succeed for portions of `z[l]` and `r[l]` for as long as they are real, however, it does not plot on real axes with  `r[l]` and `r'[l]` even if they are real.

So, what is a numerical workaround to plot them? Taking the real part with zero imaginary part is not so elegant an option I feel.

(As remote connected background I refer to Zeeman/ R. Thom's views, but in mathematics, perhaps, there is no such catastrophe. We know what happens in a geometric singularity.)

Comment: Related (duplicates?): [(17202)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17202), [(34365)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34365), [(75405)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75405) -- In V10.1, everything works fine without using `Re` or `Chop`, but in earlier versions, that's the solution you find in these links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want to plot?

```
 ParametricPlot[Chop @ {z[l], r[l]}, {l, 0, 2},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick},
   AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: zr]

```
ParametricPlot[Chop @ {r[l], r'[l]}, {l, 0, 2},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick},
  AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: rdr]

Comment: When the imaginary component is very small making it numeric real, why cannot it be made really real by automatic chopping off the imaginary part inside the software?

Comment: As noted in the comments to your question, in V10.1, the explicit application of `Chop` is not needed, so the problem you encountered seems to be fixed.

Comment: thanks. ( no future cusp catastrophes !)